# Which variable does gdb claim it segfaults

Tags: variables, segmentation-fault, gdb, fortran, memory-address

I am an engeneer, not a code writer. (from France, so please excuse my sometimes poor english) So I lack basig knowledge, e.g. "gdb" :

A fortran program that I am developing segfaults at an openmp clause.
I'm given by gdb the address of the memory location that the program cannot reach, but I would like to know the NAME of the offending variable, to be helped in finding what goes wrong.

How can I be given the NAME of the variable located at 0x00002aaaaab455ca, gdb says in my precise case ?

Thank's,
 David

I may need to have a gdb script give me all the adresses of all the variables, but I do not even know how to do that neither; could you give me an address where to learn that, please ? Thank you.

EDIT: I use gfortran this way :
$ gfortran input.f -g -freal-8-real-16 -o output

EDIT2: Excuse me, of course I DO use -fopenmp; and I also use all of the warnings in a preceding compilation, in order to have very "clean" code for the production runs. (I've checked whatever possible and I just need the NAME of the variable that segfaults, in order to correct the calculation of it's index)

Comment: How do you compile your code? Which compiler? Which flags? How does the relevant code look like? Edit your question please.

Comment: You aren't using compiler option `-fopenmp`, so the compiler isn't using OpenMP.   Try using `-fcheck=all` and perhaps the compiler will find the problem without needing to use gdb.   For debugging, I suggest options: `-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all`

Comment: Why do you show us a command line in edit 1 and then say that you actually use something else? What exactly do you use then? Do not use edit 1, edit 2, edit 3... but make it one good and clear question. Please read how to ask a good question in the help section.

Comment: Excuse me Vladimir, this is not very clear really; it is because I'm on holidays and I wonder what I would be able to do at work on monday; so the information I give only rely on my memory/recall of the facts that I believe important at the time of each answer.
 I will only be able to give you the exact commands on monday; see you next week ;-)

Comment: Hi Vladimir F, happy new year; the way I actually compile the program is :
$ echo; echo; echo; echo; echo; gfortran /S/DATA/DVA/F90/BN/SS.f -fdefault-real-8 -fbounds-check -fopenmp -g -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wconversion -Wsurprising -Wunderflow -Wunused-labels -Wline-truncation -W -o ./S 2>tmp; m tmp
 And I run it this way, which ends correctly on a single thread, but still with wrong results; so it's my own responsibility.
$ 2>&1 ./S 1 p2srfd04BAR el04BAR.inp
 Thank you.
David

Answer (score 3):

> could you give me an address where to learn that

Such questions are off-topic here, but here is a [book](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) on GDB.

You have two choices:

1. You can learn just enough GDB to debug this problem, or
2. You can bribe someone more familiar to do it for you.

Assuming you want to do (1), here are some of the commands you may find useful:

- `where` (tells you where in the program you are crashing)
- `x/i $pc` (tells you the instruction that caused the crash)
- `info registers` (this, together with above, should give you the exact address that your program tried to access)
- `info locals`, `info globals`, `info addr 0x....` (gives you a list of local and global variables, and may also tell you what you need about the crashing address).

If above isn't enough, you should edit your question to show how far you got (i.e. the output from above commands), and we may be able to help you more. But it's hard to debug over such a low-speed connection, so you really should try to find someone closer to you (i.e. use option (2)).

Comment: Ok Employed Russian, I will try to do as you mention as (1), ie "learn just enough GDB to debug this problem"; up to now, the only thing I know with gdb is bt-backtrace; it shows me on which line of my code the program crashes. So I can guess which is the offending array, and correct the calculation of its index. (almost always the same problem, or any other is too easy)
 But, using OPENMP, it crashes on the main "PARALLEL DO" directive, which clauses enumerates all the variables in the program, putting them either PRIVATE to one single thread or SHARED between all the threads.  (continued...)

Comment: So ALL the variables are named on the same instruction, and I can't guess which one of them goes wrong.
 BTW, I don't mind debugging on such a slow connection, it gives me enough hints, and there is really nobody close to me that could help me, since even nobody in my company knows fortran.
 Bye,
David

Comment: @dva2tlse Please read my answer *again*. Your problem is unlikely to have anything to do with variables. Your *first* step should be to look at the instruction which caused the crash. Until you tell us what that instruction is (and the values of registers), no further help can come to you.

Comment: Ok I will do that at work on monday, but I was just wondering from here at home how I could try and understand what happens.

Comment: @dva2tlse I'll repeat one last time: to understand what happens, your *very first step* should be to look at the instruction that causes the crash.

Comment: Ok Employed Russian, as I told you I will look at that on monday; see you next year ;-)

Comment: Hello Employed Russian, Happy new year; you must be right saying the problem "is unlikely to have anything to do with variables", because it does not even work correctly on a single thread. So thank tou to have convinced me of this fact. So it's over for the moment, or partially solved and useless.